# Django can't read message files

Tags: python, django, internationalization

I'm trying to activate french language on my project using django internationalization framework.

Here's my urls.py

```
from django.conf.urls import patterns, include, url
from django.conf.urls.i18n import i18n_patterns
urlpatterns = i18n_patterns('',
    url('$^', 'test_inter.views.test')
)
```

Here's my views.py

```
from django.utils.translation import ugettext, get_language
from django.http import HttpResponse
def test(request):
     return HttpResponse('%s - %s' % (get_language(), ugettext('test_en')))
```

Here's my settings.py

```
# Django settings for test_inter project.

DEBUG = True
TEMPLATE_DEBUG = DEBUG
ADMINS = (
)

MANAGERS = ADMINS

DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.mysql', # Add 'postgresql_psycopg2', 'mysql', 'sqlite3' or 'oracle'.
        'NAME': 'sass01aud',                      # Or path to database file if using sqlite3.
        'USER': 'root',                      # Not used with sqlite3.
        'PASSWORD': '',                  # Not used with sqlite3.
        'HOST': 'localhost',                      # Set to empty string for localhost. Not used with sqlite3.
        'PORT': '3306',                      # Set to empty string for default. Not used with sqlite3.
    }
}


TIME_ZONE = 'America/Chicago'

LOCALE_PATHS = (
    '/Users/osasseville/Documents/workspace/test_inter/src/locale'                
)

def gettext(s): s
LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en'
LANGUAGES = (
    ('en', gettext('English')),
    ('fr', gettext('French')),
)
USE_I18N = True
USE_L10N = True       # not required for this demo but important

SITE_ID = 1
MEDIA_ROOT = ''
MEDIA_URL = ''
STATIC_ROOT = ''
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATICFILES_DIRS = (
)
STATICFILES_FINDERS = (
    'django.contrib.staticfiles.finders.FileSystemFinder',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles.finders.AppDirectoriesFinder',
#    'django.contrib.staticfiles.finders.DefaultStorageFinder',
)

# Make this unique, and don't share it with anybody.
SECRET_KEY = '%!q$#o%9wta*m31c_nhp(x777_-^@&amp;ebu%6da&amp;^=a6t)nt(ux)'
TEMPLATE_LOADERS = (
    'django.template.loaders.filesystem.Loader',
    'django.template.loaders.app_directories.Loader',
)

MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES = (
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.locale.LocaleMiddleware',
)
ROOT_URLCONF = 'test_inter.urls'
WSGI_APPLICATION = 'test_inter.wsgi.application'
TEMPLATE_DIRS = (
)
INSTALLED_APPS = (
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.sites',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'test_inter',
)
LOGGING = {
    'version': 1,
    'disable_existing_loggers': False,
    'filters': {
        'require_debug_false': {
            '()': 'django.utils.log.RequireDebugFalse'
        }
    },
    'handlers': {
        'mail_admins': {
            'level': 'ERROR',
            'filters': ['require_debug_false'],
            'class': 'django.utils.log.AdminEmailHandler'
        }
    },
    'loggers': {
        'django.request': {
            'handlers': ['mail_admins'],
            'level': 'ERROR',
            'propagate': True,
        },
    }
}
```

I've created a *locale* folder and run django-admin

```
osasseville:src osasseville$ pwd
/Users/osasseville/Documents/workspace/test_inter/src
osasseville:src osasseville$ mkdir locale
osasseville:src osasseville$ django-admin.py makemessages -l fr
processing language fr
```

I have edited my locale/fr/LC_MESSAGES/django.po

```
# SOME DESCRIPTIVE TITLE.
# Copyright (C) YEAR THE PACKAGE'S COPYRIGHT HOLDER
# This file is distributed under the same license as the PACKAGE package.
# FIRST AUTHOR <EMAIL@ADDRESS>, YEAR.
#
msgid ""
msgstr ""
"Project-Id-Version: PACKAGE VERSION\n"
"Report-Msgid-Bugs-To: \n"
"POT-Creation-Date: 2013-02-19 18:23-0500\n"
"PO-Revision-Date: YEAR-MO-DA HO:MI+ZONE\n"
"Last-Translator: FULL NAME <EMAIL@ADDRESS>\n"
"Language-Team: LANGUAGE <LL@li.org>\n"
"Language: \n"
"MIME-Version: 1.0\n"
"Content-Type: text/plain; charset=UTF-8\n"
"Content-Transfer-Encoding: 8bit\n"
"Plural-Forms: nplurals=2; plural=(n > 1)\n"

#: test_inter/settings.py:31
msgid "English"
msgstr "Anglais"

#: test_inter/settings.py:32
msgid "French"
msgstr "Francais"

#: test_inter/views.py:5
msgid "test_en"
msgstr "test_fr"
```

Finally, I have compiled my messages.

```
osasseville:src osasseville$ python manage.py compilemessages -l fr
processing file django.po in     /Users/osasseville/Documents/workspace/test_inter/src/locale/fr/LC_MESSAGES
```

When I run my dev server this is the result:

/fr/ give me fr - test_en
/en/ give me en - test_en

As you can see, my language is switching but it cannot show the test_fr in my message file.

Comment: I found a fix, but I still dont understand it. If I create a new database, everything works well...